# $scope.name.push() not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

As far as I know I'm doing nothing wrong, but it just won't work.
I'm just trying to push a string into a $scope.Array.

This is my code:

```
var _length = currentNieuws.textImages.length;
for (var i = 0; i < _length; i++) {
    var _str = currentNieuws.textImages[i];
    $scope.textImages.push(_str);
}
```

Screenshot of debugging, the string is not empty as you can see:
[image]

and as you can see here it is still undefined:
[image]

Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: this happens because you get from _currentNieuws.textImages_ and add to `$scope.textImages`. And i sure you not init this array in _$scope_. Somewhere above you should do `$scope.textImages = []`

Comment: $scope.textImages = [] befora starting the loop

Comment: @ÁgostonSzékely you're right, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because you get from `currentNieuws.textImages` and add to `$scope.textImages`.
And i sure you not init this array in *$scope*.
Somewhere above you should do `$scope.textImages = []`

Or yet another variant: avoid loop and do

```
$scope.textImages = currentNieuws.textImages;
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to define the`$scope.textImages` before the loop as follow:

```
$scope.textImages = [];
```

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem yes now it works fine. I feel so stupid now.

Comment: It always happens even with the best :D.